# PyPI Server Response 410

Tags: python, pypi

I was trying to upload my python package to PyPI and facing a 410 error.

```
running register
running check
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
 1. use your existing login,
 2. register as a new user,
 3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
 4. quit
Your selection [default 1]:
1
Username: DrLC
Password:
Registering sas_dataset to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (410): Gone (This API has been deprecated and removed from 
legacy PyPI in favor of using the APIs available in the new PyPI.org 
implementation of PyPI (located at https://pypi.org/). For more information 
about migrating your use of this API to PyPI.org, please see 
https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading. For 
more information about the sunsetting of this API, please see 
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-June/030766.html)
```

It seems that my package has a duplicated name with another package. But I cannot find any package with the same name on PyPI.

I'm still quite new to this, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The commands I used are "python setup.py sdist" "python setup.py register" and "python setup.py upload". The error took place during "python setup.py register"

Comment: I fixed it by using twine, with nothing changed... No idea what caused this error.

Comment: `python setup.py register` doesn't work at all now; even `twine register` no longer required. `python setup.py upload` doesn't work either because of changes in protocol; only `twine upload` works.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I read the handbook and noticed it. Thanks a lot!